# Typescript import module error

Tags: typescript

Im kinda new working with typescript i haven this small test file im using to practice, and still dont get what is wrong here.

**app.ts**

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import { ShareModule } from './modules/share.module';

export class AppModule {
  constructor(public share: ShareModule) { }

  public getphotos(): void {
    this.share.logPhotos();
  }

}

const app = new AppModule();
```

**share.module.ts**

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';

export class ShareModule {
  public photos: any = [
    { name: 'string' },
    { name: 'string' },
    { name: 'string' },
    { name: 'string' },
    { name: 'string' },
    { name: 'string' }
  ];
  constructor() {
  }

  public logPhotos(): void {
    this.photos.forEach((photo) => {
      console.log(photo);
    });
  }
}
```

someone to help to understand why is wrong and where is error on the code, just to make a little bit more clear i have the error the `const app = new Appmodule` is expecting  1 argument and get 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constructor of `AppModule` requires a parameter. So a param has to be passes while  using `new AppModule()`. Constructor param can be made optional by

```
constructor(public share ?: ShareModule) { }
```

Answer (score 1):

The constructor is `constructor(public share: ShareModule) { }`. It is expecting an argument of type `ShareModule`. But you are not passing any.